# Best way to safely call new on this trivial example?

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

For a school project, I have 3 classes: an Egg, a Nest, and a Hen. We need to use `new` to create an instance of each in `main`, call `display()` on each, then explicitly delete each. That's all easy.

My problem is not knowing how to properly catch a `bad_alloc`; should 1 be thrown on any of the `new` calls.

Right now, it looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace std;

    cout << "Creating new instances on the heap..." << endl;
    Egg* egg = new Egg("New Egg");
    Nest* nest = new Nest("New Nest");
    Hen* hen = new Hen("New Hen");

    cout << sizeof(*egg) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(*nest) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(*hen) << endl;


    cout << "\nCalling display() on each..." << endl;
    egg->display();
    nest->display();
    hen->display();

    cout << "\nExplicitly deleting each instance..." << endl;
    delete egg;
    delete nest;
    delete hen;


    cout << "\nDone" << endl;

}
```

I thought of wrapping the entire block from the first `new` to the last `delete` in a `try` block, then just catching a `bad_alloc`, and calling `delete` on each instance, but then I thought of the following scenario:

- `egg` is successfully created
- `nest` fails, and throws a `bad_alloc`

If I call delete on all 3 at this point, `hen` should throw another exception because it was never allocated in the first place, so it can't be free'd.

I know ideally, you wouldn't use `new` out in the open like this, but what's the best way to handle this situation? Is it too trivial and artificial to be properly handled?

Comment: _"My problem is not knowing how to properly catch a `bad_alloc`; should 1 be thrown on any of the `new` calls."_ You wrap one around all of them or have single `try {} catch {}` blocks for each of them?

Comment: Normally you'd use one of the smart pointer classes. `unique_ptr` might be a good fit here. Your assignment doesn't seem to allow it, though.

Comment: Actually, it's very well possible that you're not expected to know about the possibility of `new` failing yet, and that you're not expected to handle it.

Comment: **+1** This is a ***very*** good question. It is scenarios like this that smart pointers and other scoped "decommissioners" were designed for. I believe Ed Heal's answer will work in your case.

Comment: @hvd You're right. At this point we aren't required to deal with such situations. My problem is that 20% of my mark for the program is a "test plan" that requires  testing at least 3 scenarios where the program can fail/do something unintended. The only i/o it does though is the `cout`s in main, and the `display()` method. It's basically just 3 nested classes, 2 of which contain an instance of one of the other 3 classes. I'm grasping at straws to find a failure point; let alone 3. Thus, this question.

Comment: @hvd: I think what's more important is that normally you'd not use dynamic allocation for these objects in the first place. This is IMO the #1 guideline for C++ dynamic memory allocation: "When in doubt, don't." Only then should `std::unique_ptr` et al enter the game.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Basically, thinking about test plans is a very good. But I wonder myself how three different failure scenarios should be created if there is no input, your only communication with external resources is memory allocation and we suppose your code is error-free.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The test plan requirement is across every project that we do. Most contain something like reading from a file or stdIn, or converting a String to an int, so usually there's something that can fail. This one is overly simple though.

Comment: @ChristianHackl and the requirement for the project was to dynamically allocate the 3 in main; regardless of how little sense it makes in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this

1. Declare them first. Set to `nullptr`
2. Start the try block
3. Allocate.
4. Catch - delete them - delete nullprt is a noop

Comment: Awesome, thank you. What does "is a noop" mean? It will just silently allow it?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, "noop" stands for "no operation". The fact that `delete nullptr` is a noop means that deleting a null pointer is guaranteed to do nothing. This implies that it's not an error to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could write a long program like the following (but I do not know if it is necessarily better)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  using namespace std;
  Egg* egg;
  Nest* nest;
  Hen* hen;

  cout << "Creating new instances on the heap..." << endl;
  try {
    egg = new Egg("New Egg");
  } catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) {
     std::cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << '\n';
     return 1;
  }

 try {
    nest = new Nest("New Nest");
  } catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) {
     std::cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << '\n';
     delete egg;
     return 1;
  } 

  try {
    hen = new Hen("New Hen");
  } catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) {
     std::cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << '\n';
     delete egg;
     delete nest;
     return 1;
  }

  cout << sizeof(*egg) << endl;
  cout << sizeof(*nest) << endl;
  cout << sizeof(*hen) << endl;


  cout << "\nCalling display() on each..." << endl;
  egg->display();
  nest->display();
  hen->display();

  cout << "\nExplicitly deleting each instance..." << endl;
  delete egg;
  delete nest;
  delete hen;


  cout << "\nDone" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Woah Nelly. I considered something along these lines, but I didn't like how long it would make the main procedure.

Comment: @Carcigenicate And this would be one reason why any reasonably modern C++ developer would not do it this way.  That's what `std::make_unique` is for (and other smart pointers).  Let the RAII techniques do their job.  (Heck, in this simplistic example, there's no point in dynamically creating the objects in the first place...)

Comment: @AndreKostur Thanks. This is like the fourth mention of smart pointers, so I'll definitely look them up; although depending on what they look like, might be overkill for this particular example.